# How to avoid "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" and infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-context

I have written a react-js component like this:

```
import Auth from "third-party-auth-handler";
import { AuthContext } from "../providers/AuthProvider";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.isCurrentUserAuthenticated()
      .then(user => {
        setAuth({isAuthenticated: true, user});
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);
};
```

With the following AuthProvider component:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

const initialState = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null };
const AuthContext = createContext(initialState);

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
};

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

Everything works just fine, but I get this warning in the developer's console:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setAuth'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

If I add `setAuth` as a dependency of `useEffect`, the warning vanishes, but I get `useEffect()` to be run in an infinite loop, and the app breaks out.
I understand this is probably due to the fact that `setAuth` is reinstantiated every time the component is mounted.
I also suppose I should probably use `useCallback()` to avoid the function to be reinstantiated every time, but I really cannot understand how to use `useCallback` with a function from `useContext()`

Comment: Could you show the AuthContext code?

Comment: To show you how to use `useCallback`, we'll need to see where `setAuth` is defined (ie, where you render an `AuthContext.Provider`)

Comment: What official pattern did you follow here (whose docs explain that you should do things this way)? Because effects are for side-effects that should happen when a component instance updates. You shouldn't make other code call effects directly, that code should instead update the owning component, so that _it_ triggers the appropriate side effect.

Comment: I am not seeing an infinite loop - https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-infinite-loop-q5xk4. The code is exactly as you have provided.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: you are right, I did probably mix some different documentation sources and examples... Do you mean I should not call setAuth in the useEffect() in MyComponent?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run useEffect call just once when component is mounted, I think you should keep it as it is, there is nothing wrong in doing it this way. However, if you want to get rid of the warning you should just wrap setAuth in useCallback like you mentioned.

```
const setAuthCallback = useCallback(setAuth, []);
```

And then put in in your list of dependencies in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Auth.isCurrentUserAuthenticated()
      .then(user => {
        setAuth({isAuthenticated: true, user});
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, [setAuthCallback]);
```

If you have control over AuthContext Provider, it's better to wrap your setAuth function inside.

After OP edit:
This is interesting, setAuth is a function from useState which should always be identical, it shouldn't cause infinite loop unless I'm missing something obvious

Edit 2:

Ok I think I know the issue. It seems like calling

```
setAuth({ isAuthenticated: true, user });
```

is reinstantianting AuthProvider component which recreates setAuth callback which causes infinite loop.
Repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leftpad-i6tw7?file=/src/App.js:973-1014

In normal circumstances your example should work just fine

Comment: Yes, I have control over `AuthContext`, I'll add it to the question... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I had to use `setAuthCallback({isAuthenticated: true, user})` instead of `setAuth({isAuthenticated: true, user})` `in the useEffect`, and `const setAuthCallback = useCallback(setAuth, [setAuth])` (with the setAuth dependency) to avoid an additional warning. Now it works, and no warnings. But I'd prefer to wrap the `setAuth` inside the `AuthContext` in `useCallback()`, if possible,...

Comment: I can assure you it **does** cause an infinite loop... :-)

Comment: I see. But how to let my example work in the circustances I did explain?

Comment: @Marcos I think the crucial part is that - why is this actually happening in your example?  Why AuthProvider gets recreated (not rerendered) when setAuth is called?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of `useContext`.
If you are changing the context value via `setAuth` then the nearest provider being updated with latest context then your component again updated due to this.

To avoid this re-rendering behavior you need to memorize your component.

**This is what official doc says**

> Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext)
> and returns the current context value for that context. The current
> context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest
> <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree.
>
> When the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the component updates,
> this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed
> to that MyContext provider. Even if an ancestor uses React.memo or
> shouldComponentUpdate, a rerender will still happen starting at the
> component itself using useContext.

Like this ?

```
function Button() {
  let appContextValue = useContext(AppContext);
  let theme = appContextValue.theme; // Your "selector"

  return useMemo(() => {
    // The rest of your rendering logic
    return <ExpensiveTree className={theme} />;
  }, [theme])
}
```

Comment: But you could still wrap your setAuth function in useCallback in the provider, can't you?

Comment: @MistyK: Yes, I could, but it's not clear to me how to do it exactly...

Answer (score 0):

I did finally solve not using `useCallback` in `MyComponent`, but in ContextProvider:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, createContext } from "react";

const initialState = { authorized: false, user: null };

const AuthContext = createContext(initialState);

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(initialState);
  const setAuthPersistent = useCallback(setAuth, [setAuth]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth: setAuthPersistent }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
};

export { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

I am not sure this is the best pattern, because code is not so straightforward and self-explaining, but it works, with no infinite loop nor any warning...

Comment: Did it really solve the issue? It doesn't really make much sense - setAuthPersistent is always equivalent to setAuth. It should cause the same issues which you had before.

Comment: @Mistyk: you're right! I did try to use simply setAuth again, in context provider, and everything works smootly, no warning and no loop... I'm afraid I can't understand what was changed from the situation with the loop... Sorry everybody who worked on this thread... :-(

Comment: I told you it's suspicious :)